# How to remove already present double quotes from strings in Objects in Angular?

Tags: html, json, angular, object

Using Angular, Data is being recieved in Object form, from the Database to the Backend to the Frontend. In HTML:

```
<h3>Payslip for the month of {{dataout[0].MonthYear | json }}</h3>
```

Where Dataout is the Object recieved which is having multiple entries. The Problem is that when I run the Project, then on website it shows the result like:

**Payslip for the month of "February, 2022"**

Instead it should show it like:

**Payslip for the month of February, 2022**

All strings are being shown in double quotes like above.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance (I am a newbie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using the `json` pipe.

Just remove the `| json` at then end of your interpolation.

Comment: But sometimes without ```json``` pipe, it won't work. It only shows ```[Object object]```. Can you kindly tell where to use ```json``` and where not?

Comment: `json` pipe is used to display object and arrays like `JSON.stringify` would do. You use it mainly for debug purposes.